# Перерисовка формы

Tags: delphi

Есть процедура которая рисует сетку и круг на форме. Эта процедура вызывается при изменении   `SpinEdit`(событие `OnChange`) и при изменении размеров окна (событие `OnResize`). В процедуре круг рисуется в зависимости от значения `SpinEdit`. Вопрос: как сделать чтобы круг изменял свое положение на форме прямо при изменении `SpinEdit` (он его изменяет только при изменении размеров формы по значениям `SpinEdit`) в реальном времени? Почему круг двигается только при событии `OnResize`(формы) а не `OnChange`(`SpinEdit`) хотя они выполняют одну процедуру?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенести рисование сетки в `OnPaint`. В onResize код убрать. Проверить, что работает от изменения размера.
Потом в `OnChange` spinedit'a в конец добавить Repaint, который перерисует форму.

Comment: При переносе процедуры в OnPaint окно начинает очень сильно мерцать подвисать (похоже на бесконечную перерисовку окна)

Comment: м, если бы оно так подвисало при изменении spinedit - тогда ещё можно понять. Случайно repaint в конец onPaint не поместили?

Comment: Спасибо, все работает после включения двойной буферации.